# What Modifications in below Code are required to return Function Level Metrics like Cyclomatic Complexity by passing Function Name using Sonar Api

Tags: java, web-services, sonarqube

I have written the code but it returns average Function level metrics of a project.
Need Modifications in Code to return Function Level Metrics like Cyclomatic Complexity by passing function Name/ method name using Sonar Api

```
import java.util.List;
import org.sonar.wsclient.Sonar;
import org.sonar.wsclient.services.Measure;
import org.sonar.wsclient.services.ResourceQuery;



public class SonarApi_1 {


    static String resourceKey = "Project_Name";

    //Measures which will be returned

    static String[] MEASURES_TO_GET = new String[]{"file_complexity", "class_complexity","function_complexity","lcom4","complexity","ncloc","functions","files","classes","packages"};
    public static Sonar localSonar;

  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
        try {

        //  To Create Connection Using Resource Key which is Project name , user Name and Password

      localSonar = Sonar.create("http://illin018:8000", "User_name", "Password");

            ResourceQuery query = ResourceQuery.createForMetrics(resourceKey, MEASURES_TO_GET);
            query.setIncludeTrends(true);
            Object resource =  localSonar.find(query);
            //To get measures               

        List<Measure> allMeasures = ((org.sonar.wsclient.services.Resource) resource).getMeasures();


            for (Measure measure : allMeasures) {
                System.out.println("Statements : " + measure.getMetricKey()
                        + " === " + measure.getFormattedValue());
                }
            System.out.println("lcom4 means Lack of Cohesion of Functions");
            System.out.println("ncloc means Non Commenting Lines of Code");



            } catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                }


    }


}
```

O/p

```
Statements : ncloc === 129,919
Statements : classes === 823
Statements : files === 821
Statements : packages === 86
Statements : functions === 5,205
Statements : complexity === 25,393
Statements : class_complexity === 30.9
Statements : function_complexity === 4.9
Statements : file_complexity === 30.9
Statements : lcom4 === 1.1
lcom4 means Lack of Cohesion of Functions
ncloc means Non Commenting Lines of Code
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. What is the question? What happens when you run the code currently?

Comment: Currently It returns Project Level Metrics for a Particular project.                    Statements : ncloc === 129,919
Statements : classes === 823
Statements : files === 821
Statements : packages === 86
Statements : functions === 5,205
Statements : complexity === 25,393
Statements : class_complexity === 30.9
Statements : function_complexity === 4.9
Statements : file_complexity === 30.9
Statements : lcom4 === 1.1
lcom4 means Lack of Cohesion of Functions
ncloc means Non Commenting Lines of Code.                             I want that when i pass method/function name I am able to get metrics.

Comment: I want to know how can i pass Method/Function Name and Get back metrics values for the passed function

Comment: @WarrenFaith The code which I wrote abobe works fine. There was some errors which you edited while posting the question in comments placing.Thanks for the same. But kindly suggest the additional code which I need to write to get function level metrics like Cyclometric Complexity. My code currently returns sim total of all functions Cyclometric Complexity in a particular project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SonarQube does not store the metrics for classes and methods, but only for files, directories, modules and projects. We developed a custom plugin that can provide these metrics for you, called [SourceMeter plugin for SonarQube](http://sourcemeter.com). Currently supported SonarQube versions are v3.7.4, v4.0 and v4.1. But we almost done with new version of the plugin (version 6.0), that supports from SQ 4.2 to 4.3.2. You can find an online demo [here](http://sonarqube.frontendart.com/).

UPDATE:

If you want to get class or method level metrics through the [Web Service API](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Web+Service+API), then you should call the [setQualifiers()](http://docs.sonarsource.org/latest/apidocs/org/sonar/wsclient/services/ResourceQuery.html#setQualifiers(java.lang.String...)) method of your ResourceQuery object. The qualifier of a method is "MET" and "JavaClass" for a JAVA class. You can try it in your browser, just change the URL bar to `{localhost:9000}/api/resources?metrics=ncloc&qualifiers=MET`. For example on our online demo: http://sonarqube.frontendart.com/api/resources?resource=506268&depth=-1&metrics=ncloc&qualifiers=MET

Comment: Hi @L.Lango Thanks for the reply, I will try with this. Can you also tell in case I have file name or directory name, how can return value using sonar api and call through java coding

Comment: @MukulBhasin, it isn't clear what do you want. It depends on that what value do you want to return and return to where? :) But I think you should create a new question for that and give more details. Do you want to get the SourceMeter's function and class level metrics through the Web Service API?

Comment: Yes, Through web service api. I want to return the values of method level metrics by passing method name as input.

Comment: I see. Updated the answer. I hope it helps for you.